# Error: $ is not defined in Angular Universal

Tags: angular-universal

I am using jQuery in my Angular Universal project.

I have installed jQuery and invoked it in **angular.json** file as follows :

```
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"
            ]
```

I have declared the variables in **app.component.ts** as follows:

```
declare var $: any;
```

But when I run the app, I get following list of errors:

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined 
> TypeError: window.matchMedia is not a function 
> ReferenceError: location is not defined

Everything was working fine in the regular Angular app (without server side), but not working in the Universal app (with server side).

Comment: Try to resist the urge to use jquery in angular. You don't need it. Furthermore, doing DOM manipulation through javascript messes up the angular change-detection and just gets you further away from home

Comment: Did you find any solution? Same issue on my side